# Sylvester Stallone on Donald Trump - "Dickensian character" and "larger than life"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

According to Wikipedia:

> In the 2016 election he described Donald Trump as a "Dickensian character" and "larger than life,"

This piece of information is retrieved from the article: Sylvester Stallone on Donald Trump, Republicans and Running for Office

> “I love Donald Trump,” he said. “He’s a great Dickensian character. You know what I mean? There are certain people like Arnold, Babe Ruth, that are bigger than life. But I don’t know how that translates”—he let out a laugh—“to running the world.”

So I can say it's a compliment, great :) But what exactly do "Dickensian character" and "larger than life" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dickensian" refers to the famous author [**Charles Dickens**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Dickens), known for writing novels with characters who are "larger than life":

> [**larger than life**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/larger-than-life) (adj): *1. greater, grander, etc. than most others of its kind, 2. exceptionally striking or colourful*

Stallone is saying that Trump appears like someone out of an entertaining novel, with a showmanship and dramatic personality that make him impossible to ignore.

It's a *kind* of a compliment, in that implies someone is *memorable* -- but it also implies that he is somehow *artificial* and *inauthentic*, as if his personality was all based on some premeditated script or story.

Comment: So larger than life in this context = exceptionally striking or colourful?

Comment: @123iamking  Someone "larger" (more grandiose) than "life" (real people).  So yes, exceptionally interesting or colorful, but possibly in a way that is somewhat *artificial* or *unreal*, like a character in a novel.